# How do you describe an organization attaining a certain age?

Tags: tenses

Is it correct to say "Google will turn 18 in 2016"?

What is a better way to describe an organization attaining a certain age (in all tenses)?

Comment: It looks fine to me; what's wrong with "turn"? Do you want something more formal?

Comment: Google will celebrate its 18th anniversary (of the foundation) on X date in 2016.

Comment: Google **will complete/completes** 18 years in 2016. Alternatively, if you are writing this *in* 2016, you will say *Google completes 18 years this year*.

Comment: @MamtaD - The O.P. asks for a *better* way to describe it, not a *different* way to describe it.

Answer (score 2):

***Google's XXth [Birthday](https://www.google.it/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=google%2010th%20birthday)***  is the expression commonly used, but you may well use the expression "turned XX".

As in :

> - Coca-Cola Celebrates its [100th Birthday](http://www.wallpaper.com/lifestyle/pop-icon-the-coca-cola-bottle-celebrates-its-100th-birthday-with-a-year-long-campaign).

(www.wallpaper.com/lifestyle/pop-icon)